# Android: one fragment turning into two fragments on one page

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity that has within it one fragment that takes up the whole screen. At some point in the app flow, the user can go to another screen in the same activity that is composed of two seperate fragments. So you can imagine it as:

Fragment A (100% of the screen) -> Fragment B (50%) + Fragment C (50%)

I can think of two ways of doing this and neither one of them is particularly good. The first is to set a layout for the activity that has in it one container that will hold Fragment A, and then have Fragment A open subfragments B and C inside it. I'm trying to avoid using subfragments because it leads to unusual lifecycle bugs and it also isn't supported by all version of the api.

The second way is to have two layouts for the activity - one layout having a single container, and the second one having two containers and then switch between them at the appropriate moment with setcontentview. I have to admit that I'm not too happy about that solution either, since it means the user will see the screen redraw white instead of a nice transition effect.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this most efficiently? Note that I do want everything to remain under one activity - logically it should be this way. There's no logical point in having two seperate activities for this UI movement.

Comment: What about having two containers in the MainActivity? When Fragment A is in use, container 1 takes up the full screen. When fragment B + C are there then you use both containers taking up 50% of the screen?

Comment: You could have a `LinearLayout` composed of two containers, one initially set with weight `100` and the other with weight `0`. At runtime you can programmatically adjust their weight.

Comment: that sounds like it could work - I'll give it a shot. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by having two containers and setting the top one to wrap_content height, visibility=invisible and not populating it at all. When I need to move to the two pane setup I populate the invisibile container and set it's visibility to visible which causes it to remeasure. When moving back from the two pane to the single pane call remove on the fragment that populates the top pane.